# Make (g)vim buffer a remote file

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, remote, gvim

I regularly work remotely on a linux machine using vim.
Sadly the connection to the remote host is not very good, giving me a very tough time.
Is there a way to make my locally running vim or gvim access a remote file (storing the buffer locally) and write the file back to the host immediately?

If not, what other ways do you know to work efficiently on a remote host with a bad connection? I'm getting tired of rsyncing my files back and forth, especially when developing and doing a lot of minor changes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *netrw* plugin ships with Vim and allows transparent access to networked files. If you have SSH access to the system, use:

```
vim scp://hostname/path/to/file
```

(Also from with Vim via `:edit scp://...`; see `:help netrw` for details.)

Comment: And `vim scp://hostname/path/to/directory/` to list a remote directory.

Comment: Note that `scp://hostname/path/to/file` is relative to the connecting user's home dir (`~/path/to/file`), but adding a leading slash will get you root-relative paths, e.g.: `scp://hostname//usr/local/share/path/to/something`.